# How to limit the number of forgot password reset attempts in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django's built-in forgot password reset form and views.

I want to limit the number of reset password email attempts. By default Django allows you to send unlimited reset password emails and I want to set a limit.

Answer (score -1):

You can try django allauth package[alluth docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). 
And you can configure it according to your requirements[configuration docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)